# Error creating Typeface

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

When I try to create a new `Typeface` using this piece of code on my `Product` class (custom class, has `getView()` method to populate a `ListView`)

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/cambriab.ttf");
```

I get the following stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
    at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
    at com.darkraven.shoppinglist.Category.getView(Category.java:133)
    at com.darkraven.shoppinglist.ProductListAdapter.getView(ProductListAdapter.java:40)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2179)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1641)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2014)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14290)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14290)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14290)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14290)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14290)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5124)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

context is the main `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your ttf file placed in fonts folder in the assets , even the below code will work, or I can say it works for me ::

```
Typeface helveticaMedCond = Typefaces.get(getApplicationContext(), "fonts/Helvetica 67 Medium #2BD9AB.TTF");
```

before that cross verify whether you are using the same font name that is placed in the fonts folder or not.

Comment: Yes, the font is on the fonts folder. I'm on Android Studio.